# selecting div that contains div with a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several outer divs, all of them contain 3 inner divs `class1` `class2` `class3`. I want to select the outer div based on the value attribute of its inner div that has `class1`. For example, I want to select the first div because its `class1` div has value `x`. How do I do this with jquery?

```
<div> <-----this is the div I want to select
  <div class="class1" value="x"></div>
  <div class="class2" value="y"></div>
  <div class="class3" value="z"></div>
</div>

<div> 
  <div class="class1" value="a"></div>
  <div class="class2" value="b"></div>
  <div class="class3" value="c"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was:

```
$('.class1[value="x"]').parent();
```

But I wasn't sure of the syntax (edit: it works). This, however, could work as well:

```
$('.class1').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("value") == "x";
}).parent();
```

Note however, these will only return the *first* parent (in the case of multiple child divs having a matching "value" attribute). If you want to do something with multiple parent matches, you could iterate through the result with `$.each` and look at them individually:

```
$('.class1[value="x"]').each(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `:has` selector

```
var elem = $('div:has(.class1[value="x"])');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').has('div[value=x]');
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/ekucen/edit#javascript,html,live)

```
$('div:has([value=x])').closest('div');
```

[demo 2](http://jsbin.com/ekucen/2/edit#javascript,html,live)

```
$('div[value=x]').parents('div');
```

[demo 3](http://jsbin.com/ekucen/4/edit#javascript,html,live)

```
$('div>div[value=x]').parent('div');
```

[demo 4](http://jsbin.com/ekucen/5/edit)

```
$.fn.getChildVal = function(val){  
  $('[value='+val+']').parent().css({background:'red'});
};

$('div').getChildVal('x');
```

[plugin :)](http://jsbin.com/ekucen/6/edit)

From the docs:

http://api.jquery.com/closest
http://api.jquery.com/has

Answer (score 0):

You can do it so.

```
           $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div.class1 [value='x']").parent('div');
        });
```

Comment: I think this is fixed it now.

Comment: You are saying find a div with a class named `class1` and find an element inside of that has an attribute of value that is set to x. Not going to select the parent like the user wants, and will not select any elements in that code sample.

Answer (score 0):

$('div:has(.class1[value="value1"]):has(.class2[value="value2"]):has(.class3[value="value3"])');

Comment: Code-only posts like yours can be turned into answers according to [answer] by [edit]ing.